# Extend validity of SSL certificate - Any Hack

Tags: ssl, https

I have an absolute requirement of extending the validity of my SSL certificate. I have an SSL certificate pinned in the SDK which cannot be updated in time. This will lead to a huge business loss. Any way, any hack that will help me circumvent this.

PS: I know expiry date intrinsic to SSL and that's how its supposed to work. But I am desperate right now.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way (including no hack) to change an existing certificate, without invalidating the signature and changing its fingerprint. Which means that certificate validation would fail after such a change and pinning would fail too.